# Are there any Oval Track races in Europe?

Tags: auto-racing

In the US we seem to prefer oval races with high-speed banked turns to the street courses that seem to be favored in Europe.   Are there any "superspeedway" tracks in europe?

Comment: "Are there any?" is a poor question in any format.

Comment: @waxeagle - Is it the question you have a problem with or the way it is phrased.  I am open to suggested changes.

Comment: yes. honestly its not a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed. But the emphasis with respect to oval racing is in the US it seems.

Since I'm no expert in car races, I've had to [lookup Wikipedia's opinion on oval tracks being called *speedways*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval_track_racing). However, the name "speedway" also seems to be in use for motorcycle races (on tar, and off-road) as well as for ice speed skating.

The [German Wikipedia mostly lists the US Tracks](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovalkurs) but does mention one track in the [UK: Rockingham](http://www.rockingham.co.uk/) which claims to be the fastest in Europe, and the [Lausitzring in Germany](http://www.lausitzring.de/besucherportal/strecke-areal/gelaendeuebersicht.html) (German language only).